# How do I hide unavailable variants in search results in Shopify? (Debut theme)

Tags: search, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

When I search for products, the result shows that a product is sold out when the first variant (option from the product dropdown) is sold out even though other variants are available.

For example, if a product has colours red & blue (red being the first option), once the red is sold out, the product shows "sold out" in the search result. Only when you click it then you'll see the blue colour is available.

I tried adding a conditional in my search.liquid file, just after looping through the search results before rendering the results, to check if the item is available.

```
{% for item in search.results %}
{% if item.object_type == 'product' and item.available == true %}
// then rendered the products...
```

But what that does is hide products that have all the variants (options) sold out.

I can also hide variants that are sold out (like a particular colour or size of a product for example) on the product details page so it doesn't even show up as an option.

But the challenge is with the search results. It still shows sold out for any product that the first option is unavailable. Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this!
I was inspecting the page on the browser and realised I was trying to modify the wrong file (search.liquid). The file to be changed is the one that renders the cards for the products after search which is the product-card-list.liquid

I set the price to show the first available option using the first_available_variant method

```
{% if product.available %}
  {% include 'product-price', variant: product.first_available_variant %}
{% endif %}
```

That solved my search results issue.